# Syntax Error Python Text with variable

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def postLoadItemUpdate(itemid):
    r = requests.post("http://www.domain.com/ex/s/API/r/postLoadItemUpdate?id='".itemid."'")
    print(r.text)
```

what is wrong with `'".itemid."'"`

There seems to be an syntax error there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python use `+` operator for string concatenation:

```
"http://www.domain.com/ex/s/API/r/postLoadItemUpdate?id='" + itemid + "'"
```

But for string concatenation `itemid` should be a string object, otherwise you need to use `str(itemid)`.

Another alternative is to use string formatting, here type conversion is not required:

```
"http://www.domain.com/ex/s/API/r/postLoadItemUpdate?id='{}'".format(itemid)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to concatenate the strings, use the `+` operator:

```
r = requests.post("http://www.domain.com/ex/s/API/r/postLoadItemUpdate?id='" + itemid + "'")
```

Answer (score 1):

To concatenate strings you have to use `+` and if `itemid` is not a string value, you might want to apply `str` to convert that to a string.

```
"http://www.domain.com/ex/s/API/r/postLoadItemUpdate?id='" + str(itemid) + "'"
```

Answer (score 1):

String concatenation in Python works like this

```
s + itemId + t
```

not like this:

```
s . itemid . t
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you could also use [`format`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format):

```
r = requests.post("http://www.domain.com/ex/s/API/r/postLoadItemUpdate?id={0}".format(itemid))
```

In your particular use case, formal seems to be more flexible, and url changes will have little impact.

Answer (score 1):

Where to start: does `"constant string".itemid."constant string 2"` work in Python?

You need to concatenate strings differently.  Interactive mode for Python is your friend: learn to love it:

```
    $ python
    Python 2.7.5 (default, Aug 25 2013, 00:04:04)
    [GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 5.0 (clang-500.0.68)] on darwin
    Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
    >>> foo = "-itemid-"
    >>> "string1" + foo + "string2"
    'string1-itemid-string2'
```

That should give you a starting point.